# Prove by induction: For $T(1)=1$, $T(n)=T(⌊\frac{n}{2}⌋)+T(⌈\frac{n}{2}⌉)+1=O(n)$

Tags: asymptotics

I only saw one problem involving induction so I am not sure what to do here. Here is what I tried and where I got stuck:

For $n=1$, $T(1)=1\leq 1*1$, so we are covered.

The hypothesis would be that for all $k<n$, $T(k)=O(k)$. From here I believe that we could say that for all $n$ larger than some $n_0$:

$T(⌊\frac{n}{2}⌋)\leq c*⌊\frac{n}{2}⌋$ and $T(⌈\frac{n}{2}⌉)\leq c*⌈\frac{n}{2}⌉$

I believe that I am supposed to choose the same $c$ for both of them, but not completely sure.

Now this is where I get stuck:

$T(n)=T(⌊\frac{n}{2}⌋)+T(⌈\frac{n}{2}⌉)+1\leq c*⌊\frac{n}{2}⌋+c*⌈\frac{n}{2}⌉+1=c*n+1$

When I was taught this method it was stressed that it is important to prove the case for $T(n)$ for the same $c$ from the hypothesis however it does not seem possible to me here.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's helpful to determine an appropriate value for $c$ to use. You're given that $T(1) = 1$ and

$$T(n) = T\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right) + T\left(\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil\right) + 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Trying the next few values, you get

$$T(2) = T(1) + T(1) + 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$T(3) = T(1) + T(2) + 1 = 1 + 3 + 1 = 5 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

$$T(4) = T(2) + T(2) + 1 = 3 + 3 + 1 = 7 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

$$T(5) = T(2) + T(3) + 1 = 3 + 5 + 1 = 9 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

As you can see, you get $T(n) = 2n - 1$, which you can prove fairly easily by induction. However, to instead directly prove that $T(n) = O(n)$ by induction, you can use $c = 2$ and prove $T(n) \lt cn = 2n$ (although the technical definition is for $\le$, you can use just $\lt$ as that's more strict and, thus, included in $\le$). The base case is true, i.e., $T(1) = 1 \lt 2(1)$. Next, use [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction) to assume it's true for all $n \le k$ for some $k \ge 1$. Note since $T(n) \lt 2n$ for all $1 \le n \le k$, this means that $T(n) \le 2n - 1$ since it's values are all integral. Thus, using that $\left\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rfloor \le k$ and $\left\lceil\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rceil \le k$, plus that $\left\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rfloor + \left\lceil\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rceil = k + 1$ for all integers $k$, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
T(k + 1) & = T\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rfloor\right) + T\left(\left\lceil\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rceil\right) + 1 \\
& \le \left(2\left\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rfloor - 1\right) + \left(2\left\lceil\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rceil - 1\right) + 1 \\
& = 2\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rfloor + \left\lceil\frac{k+1}{2}\right\rceil\right) - 1 \\
& = 2(k + 1) - 1 \\
& \lt 2(k + 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

This shows the inductive step also holds, confirming that $T(n) \lt 2n$ for all $n \ge 1$, meaning that $T(n) = O(n)$. Note since $T(n) \lt 2n$, it's also trivially true that $T(n) \le 2n$, meaning the definition of $O$ holds for any $c \ge 2$, i.e., you have $T(n) \le cn$.

Comment: I am required to use the formal definition, using $<$ instead of $\leq$ is not allowed.

Comment: If $T(n)<2n$ then trivially $T(n)\leqslant 2n$ as well...

Comment: Of course, but $\leq$ does not mean $<$, which by the formal definition is the only thing you can assume.

Comment: @איתןלוי As Math1000 stated, if something is $\lt$, then it also $\le$. I added an extra sentence to the end of my answer stating this.

Comment: @JohnOmielan This is not what I am saying. What I am saying is that by the definition, when you assume $T(k)=O(k)$ you may only use the fact that $T(k)\leq c*k$, you don't know that $T(k)<c*k$ because it is MORE information that what the definition gives you.

Comment: @איתןלוי The question only asks you to prove that $T(n) = O(n)$, i.e., there's a $c$ such that $T(n) \le cn$, by induction, i.e., this is the final result. It *doesn't* say you need to use this in any part of the inductive proof before the conclusion, i.e., in particular, in the inductive step, i.e., that $T(k) = O(k)$. Forgetting about $O$ for now, if I wanted to prove $Q \le R$, if I can prove that $Q \lt R$, I've accomplished this since $Q \le R$ trivially holds as $\le$ means $\lt$ *or* $=$. Sometimes, in proofs, it's easier to prove a somewhat more stringent requirement than necessary.